# Django list of ids as a form field

Tags: django, django-forms

My apologizes if this question was somewhere before, but I could not find anything.

So, the question is really simple: is these any django native formfield that mimics the behavior of `request.POST.getlist('something')`?

In my UI, user creates a list of objects that he wants to save, and these objects are represented as a list of hidden inputs with the same name:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cc" value="1045">
<input type="hidden" name="cc" value="1055">
<input type="hidden" name="cc" value="1046">
```

`request.POST.getlist` does exactly what I need, but I don't want to work with the request directly, I want do to it through the form.

Comment: maybe a hidden modelchoicefield? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for the comment. Yes I found that `ModelChoiceField` is used to `ManyToMany` fields in models. On the form side, it is represented as `MultipleChoiceField/TypedMultipleChoiceField`.

So I decided to subclass this field and override `validate methods`.

```
class NotValidatedMultipleChoiceFiled(forms.TypedMultipleChoiceField):
    """Field that do not validate if the field values are in self.choices"""

    def to_python(self, value):
        """Override checking method"""
        return map(self.coerce, value)

    def validate(self, value):
        """Nothing to do here"""
        pass
```